# Chave estrangeira composta - ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu durante a criação dessas 3 tabelas me deparei com o erro:

"*ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint*"

A única conclusão que consegui chegar é que o problema está com o campo *estado*, pois quando eu removo ele da foreign key o erro desaparece.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aula4exer5evolucao5;
USE aula4exer5evolucao5;

CREATE TABLE MEDICO (
    nome    varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    estado  varchar(2)  NOT NULL,
    crm     bigint      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MEDICO_PK PRIMARY KEY(estado, crm)
);

CREATE TABLE PACIENTE (
    nome            varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    dtNascimento    date        NOT NULL,
    sexo            varchar(1)  NOT NULL,
    cpf             varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    cep             bigint,
    rua             varchar(10),
    bairro          varchar(20),
    numero          INT,
    complemento     varchar(10),
    cidade          varchar(20),
    estado          varchar(2),

    CONSTRAINT PACIENTE_PK PRIMARY KEY(cpf)
);

CREATE TABLE CONSULTA_atende (
    dtHora      timestamp   NOT NULL,
    idConsulta  INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cpf         varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    estado      varchar(2)  NOT NULL,
    crm         bigint      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT CONSULTA_atende_PK PRIMARY KEY(idConsulta),
    CONSTRAINT consulta_MEDICO_FK FOREIGN KEY(estado, crm) REFERENCES MEDICO(estado, crm),
    CONSTRAINT CONSULTA_UK UNIQUE (estado, crm, dtHora)

)   ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Eu queria entender o que eu estou fazendo de errado nessa terceira tabela...

Answer (score 0):

Na tabla medico, a coluna estado ja é uma primary key, entao não pode ser uma foreign Key, por isso quando você tira da foreign key a coluna estado na terceira tabla, nao da mais erro